# unixtimestamp in rsyslog.conf

Tags: unix-timestamp, rsyslog

this is my `rsyslog.conf` template format:

```
$template userformat,"%HOSTNAME%,%syslogfacility%(%syslogFacility-text%),%syslogpriority%(%syslogpriority-text%),%syslogtag%,%timegenerated:::date-unixtimestamp%,%msg%\r\n"
```

but in the log file date of log is not in `unixtimestap` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of rsyslog are you using (`rsyslog -v`)? As far as I can tell, the feature was only introduced in rsyslog version 6.3.8.

See my [answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/541574/189647) for more details.

Comment: problem fixed . my rsyslog version was 5.8.11 . thanks for your answer